# Was there a change in Polymer 1 vs Polymer 2 for array observers?

Tags: polymer-1.0, polymer-2.x

I used Polymer 1 (latest version) plus `polymerfire` (latest version) to show a list with an index (the `seedPosition` property in my code below). In Polymer 1, the index was incremented by one when I added one object to Firebase, but when I updated everything to Polymer 2.0-preview, the index was increased by the whole list length. That suggests that the whole object gets updated and not the newly added.

The only change I made is loading all elements as `#2.0-preview` via bower, and changed the class syntax to Polymer 2 (e.g., `class ClassName extends Polymer.Element {...}`.

```
<!-- load the firebase array -->
<firebase-query app-name="firebaselogin" path="/exerciseLog" data="{{exerciseLogData}}"></firebase-query>

<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{exerciseLogData}}">
  [[tutorValues()]]
</template>

Polymer({
  properties: {
    seedPosition: {
      type: Number,
      value: -1
    }
  }

  observers: [
    "seedPositionChanged(seedPosition)"
  ],

  tutorValues: function(){
    this.set("seedPosition", this.get("seedPosition") + 1);
  }

  seedPositionChanged: function (seedPosition) {
    // Here the seed value gets called exaclty once when adding ONE element to the {{exerciseLogData}} data
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer to your question is `yes`. You should have a look at [this](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/about_20#data-system) for more details on list of changes that were introduced.

Comment: Thanks for the link. But that does effectively mean, that a new element in a list forces the whole list-dom to be redrawn instead of just drawing one new element. I'm thinking here about a chat as an example. That doesn't seem very efficient.

Comment: In `dom-repeat` list is always re-rendered if items changes. You should have a look at [iron-list](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/iron-list).

Comment: That is not what I experienced. I used a function inside each dom-repeat object that incremented a counter and returned the value. With polymer 1 the counter was incremented by 1 when adding 1 element to the array. But in polymer 2 the counter incremented as often as the length of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Try `[[tutorValues(item)]]`. Empty function calls are only called once.

Also since you are observing a primitive value, the observer should be called when setting it directly, e.g. `this.seedPosition = this.seedPosition + 1;`